# RDFLib (Python) to Sesame (JAVA)

Tags: java, python, assertion, sesame, rdflib

I have the following code in python using RDFLib and I want to translate it into JAVA using Sesame libraries.

**Python**

```
 restrictionNode= BNode()
    g.add((nodeIndividualName,rdftype,restrictionNode))
    g.add((restrictionNode, rdftype, OWL.Restriction))
    g.add((restrictionNode, OWL.onProperty, rno.is_extent_of))

   listClassNode = BNode()
   g.add((restrictionNode, OWL.allValuesFrom, listClassNode))
   g.add((listClassNode, rdftype, OWL.Class))

   arcListNode = BNode()
   g.add((listClassNode, OWL.oneOf,arcListNode ))
   Collection(g, arcListNode,arcIndividualList)
```

In the above code, g is a graph.

the above code creates the following assertion:

```
is_extent_of only ({arc_1,arc_2,arc_4})
```

I was able to create the same code but the last line. Does anyone know if there is the same notion as Collection in Sesame APIs or I should manually create the list using first and rest?

Answer (score 1):

Sesame's core library currently has no convenience functions for Collections - this is being remedied though; there are plans to add basic collection handling utilities to the core libraries in the next release.

There are several third-party Sesame extension libraries that offer this kind of thing though (for example, the [SesameTools](https://github.com/joshsh/sesametools) library has the [RdfListUtil](https://github.com/joshsh/sesametools/blob/develop/common/src/main/java/net/fortytwo/sesametools/RdfListUtil.java) class for this purpose). And of course you can construct an RDF List by hand. The basic procedure is fairly simple, something like this ought to do the trick:

```
    // use a Model to collect the triples making up the RDF list
    Model m = new TreeModel();
    final ValueFactory vf = SimpleValueFactory.getInstance();

    Resource current = vf.createBNode(); // start node of your list
    m.add(current, RDF.TYPE, RDF.LIST);

    // iterate over the collection you want to convert to an RDF List
    Iterator<? extends Value> iter = collection.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Value v = iter.next();
        m.add(current, RDF.FIRST, v);
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            Resource next = vf.createBNode();
            m.add(current, RDF.REST, next); 
            current = next;
        }
        else {
            m.add(current, RDF.REST, RDF.NIL);
        }
    }
```